# Automatically install missing WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Is there a way to tell WordPress to automatically install missing plugins from WordPress.org?

Here's a scenario: Recovering a WordPress site from a major failure, only the active theme files, one custom plugin and the database dumpfile still exist. The site requires a number of plugins from WordPress.org, but these weren't documented. The missing plugins break the site when trying to load the front or back end.

It's possible to extract a list of active plugins from the `wp-options` table, but that's kind of tedious and seems like something that should be built-in.

Comment: not directly possible with **wp-cli**, for good reason: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2217